# Visual Studio 2008 c++ Executable (Debug and Release) not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, executable

hope someone can help.

I'm currently writing a 2D game engine in c++.  When I run the application from within Visual Studio 2008 using either debug or release all goes fine.

When I then run the executable files (either debug or release) from Windows Explorer, neither work and just display a blank Window.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

1. Load project into VS 2008
2. Change configuration to "Debug"
3. Click the "Start Debugging" button
4. Application compiles and builds, all is ok
5. Application runs, all is ok
6. Close Application
7. Output window in VS shows "The program '[16672] Mouse Engine v2.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."
8. Open Windows Explorer window and locate executable file from the Debug folder in project.
9. Run executable, blank window is shown.
10. Change configuration to "Release"
11. Click the "Start Debugging" button
12. Application compiles and builds, all is ok
13. Application runs, all is ok
14. Close Application
15. Output window in VS shows "The program '[18872] Mouse Engine v2.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."
16. Open Windows Explorer window and locate executable file from the Release folder in project.
17. Run executable, blank window is shown.

Comment: Please, improve the wording of your question. As it is it doesn't make sense. (I assume, you can run your application out of VS but you cannot run it standalone (e.g. from Explorer). This might have to do with resolution of dependency DLLs which may fail in the latter case. However, this is not sufficiently answerable without more info from you.)

Comment: At a minimum you'd need to show some screen shots of the problem. We can't just guess at the causes in a vacuum! Do you have a history of what changed? (You're using some source control system, I assume?) Have you tried rolling back to last known good configuration?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply's.  Yes, the application runs fine out of VS (as both debug and release versions).  It's when I run the apps standalone from Explorer.

Comment: @Rags No. Screenshots. Ever. Error messages verbatim and stacktraces as __text__.

Comment: Based on your information, it's impossible to be more specific than "it's caused by a bug in your code". Initialise all your variables, and make sure that you're not making any assumptions about the working directory.

Comment: I'm trying to do screenshots now but not sure how there gonna help.  Screenshots from running from VS shows test game as normal with sprite tiles and text.  Screenshot from running the executable from windows explorer will just show a blank window?

Comment: @KenAllen Screenshots wouldn't provide any information, so don't make any. The code is what matters. Narrow it down and make a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks "molbdnilo".  All classes initialise all local variables within their constructor functions and release them (pointers) in the deconstructor functions.

Comment: @molbdnilo That may be difficult given the scale of the program.  As far as I can tell there are no issues as they run perfectly from VS as both debug and release.  It's just when I try to run the programs from their executables from windows explorer, they just show a blank window (even though they had just literally worked from running from VS.

Comment: Would this be a Windows permissions problem?

Comment: @PasserBy I assumed posting the code would be non-viable, as there would be far too much to post - hence something that showed some level of information about what was happening was needed. Granted, screenshots not the best option.

Comment: Is anyone actually able to answer this? I’ve put so much work into this application and it’s really bugging me that I cannot produce a workable executable file.

Comment: @KenAllen Perhaps try running with DebugView https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview running - it might be able to capture some diagnostics that you're not seeing?

Comment: @Rags Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: This may be a Windows problem as I’m having general issues with desktop not responding. I’m going to do a full reinstall.

Comment: If dlls fail to load, you generally get an error dialog telling you (finding out which dll was the problem can be tricky, but it doesn't just give you a black screen.) Can you tell if the application is consuming CPU time, despite the black screen? (i.e. is it running, but not painting correctly)

Comment: look for "dependency walker", most likely some DLL you need is not in the directory where your .exe is but basically it could be a lot of other things.

Comment: Temporarily adding [__debugbreak();](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx) to main() is a good way to debug the app when it is started that way.  Consulting my crystal ball, it says that you forgot to copy asset files to the build directory and don't yell loud enough when you can't find/open them.  Works by accident in the IDE since it makes the default directory the same as the project directory.

Comment: &Rags yep, I checked and it is and will exit when I click Esc (which is how I programmed it). I think it’s not locating my textures.

Comment: @Hans Passant what your saying sounds interesting, although I did recreate my file structures with textures within both the Debug and Release folders and still no luck :(

Comment: Right, after some deep digging into this, I’ve managed to solve the problem. All my classes initialise their own variables but I found that I had encapsulated some old code within new code. That is, I had old code testing for a result nested within new code testing for same result using different variables. The old code variables were not initialised. Guess what part this code was surrounding, yep, the load textures. I’m going to write up a full answer for this tomorrow so anyone with same problem can get a full list of things to check. Thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to check to resolve this sort of problem.

1. Check all variables are initialised. Seems obvious but this can be crucial. I found best way to solve this is to #DEFINE _LOG at start and output variable values to a log file in each function using #IFDEF _LOG. This way you can turn it on or off.
2. If your application is just a blank window, check if it is running (using CPU time). This is a good indication that something is preventing it to find any image or font files.
3. Check that the Debug or Release folder structure matches that within your project folder to ensure links to files and textures work.
4. Make sure in project preferences to set the Runtime Library entry to Multi-threaded (/MT). This should make your application less dependent on additional dll’s.
5. Check for problems in your code. See point 1 with using log files to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to look for are missing dependencies such as config files and data files that your program can't find.

You can also try Dependency Walker to make sure all your dll's are available. http://www.dependencywalker.com